# How to form the File object manually in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In `<input type = "file">`, we will get the uploaded raw file details in `onchange()` event. Using that raw file,  i have created the instance and send to xmlHttprequest post. Please refer below code

```
var file = document.getElementById("MyElement") .files[0];
var formData = new formdata();
formData.append("file", file);
var xml = new xmlhttprequest();
xml.open("post", server side method  );
xml.send(formdata);
```

It works fine.

For testing purpose, i have to send the file object manually.so 
How to form this file object manually as like the result get from the file type input?

```
document.getElementById("MyElement") .files[0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can create `File` instances directly. But a file is a blob, and blobs you can create for sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob `FormData` should be able to handle blobs just as files.

Comment: looks like File constructor is also available. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: @gp how to set the file path here

Comment: you can set file name not file path. I believe most of the browsers also don't provide file path when you use file dialog to select a file input but only file name.